# Como gerar um token aleatório de 32 bytes em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ionic

Eu preciso gerar uma string alfanumérica aleatória que precisa ter 32 bytes. 
Existe alguma função direta para fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Usando [crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) e um [array tipado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array)

```
function random32bit() {
  let u = new Uint32Array(1);
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(u);
  let str = u[0].toString(16).toUpperCase();
  return '00000000'.slice(str.length) + str;
}
```

Comment: o ".toString(16)" é usado para transformar o número em Hexadecimal certo? ou estou errado?

Answer (score 0):

[Aqui](https://gist.github.com/jed/982883) tem uma discussão muito boa sobre [UUID](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%BAnico_universal)

E aqui esta um exemplo que pode encontrar no primeiro link:

```js
function uuid() {
  return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c => (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16));
}

console.log(uuid());
```

Usando Math,

```js
function uuid() {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
  });
}

console.log(uuid())
```

Comment: "crypto.getRandomValues" não está funcionando no Ionic...

Comment: Não tem que importar o crypto no ionic? Esta aparecendo qual erro?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/373839/como-usar-requirecrypto-no-ionic-4

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto

Comment: Adicionei com Math na resposta

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?